# Where can I download Ubuntu icons from?

Tags: unity, icons, desktop-background

Is there a place where I can download the icons that are used in unity?

I wish to use them for a web page project in school.
I will be emulating the Ubuntu desktop for the purpose.
If you could include default wallpapers that would be great too!

Comment: You can find them within the Ubuntu install itself. Icons can be found in a variety of places, but many of them are in the folder `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps`. Here, you can click on the folders to open up icons with the resolution listed on the folder label. 

As for the wallpapers, they can be found in `/usr/share/backgrounds`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a lot here:

http://ubuntu-art.org/index.php?xcontentmode=8125

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post that includes all of Ubuntu's default wallpapers from 4.10 to 13.10: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/a-look-back-at-every-ubuntu-default-wallpaper

You can find the icons in /usr/share/icons on your Ubuntu installation.

You'll also find a lot of icons, themes, wallpapers for GNOME & Unity here at http://gnome-look.org